# Track reindex task

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

So I kick off reindexing on the ElasticSearch server:

```
// Start reindexing on the server
var response = client.ReindexOnServer(new ReindexOnServerRequest()
{
  Source = new ReindexSource() { Index = metadataModel.SourceIndexName },
  Destination = new ReindexDestination() {  Index = metadataModel.DestinationIndexName, OpType = Elasticsearch.Net.OpType.Create },
  WaitForCompletion = false,
  Refresh = true
});

var elasticSearchReIndexTaskId = response.Task.ToString();
```

and I got back the task ID. How can I use the Task API to track the progress of that task?

If the task is complete, would that error out or return something?

```
var response = client.TasksList(new TasksListRequest(elasticSearchTaskId));
```

Comment: You can pass the `TaskId` to `GetTask(...)`, which contains a `Completed` property on the response to know if the task has completed. This maps to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html

Comment: Interesting, there is no `GetTask(...)` in the version I am using

Comment: Which version of NEST are you using? And which version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: Nest 2.0, ES 2.4.2

Comment: which nuget package version of NEST 2.x?

Comment: Have you got the way to track to status of reindexing? I hope you are using C# Nest library for elastic.

Comment: Nope, I never found a way in v2 or v5. I am waiting for the task to disappear from list of tasks and then after a "cool-off" (when doc count stops increment in the dest. index) I compare the number of documents.